# Monitor custom kubernetes pod metrics using Prometheus

Tags: kubernetes, containers, prometheus, prometheus-node-exporter

I am using Prometheus to monitor my Kubernetes cluster. I have set up Prometheus in a separate namespace. I have multiple namespaces and multiple pods are running. Each pod container exposes a custom metrics at this end point, `:80/data/metrics` . I am getting the Pods CPU, memory metrics etc, but how to configure Prometheus to pull data from `:80/data/metrics` in each available pod ? I have used this tutorial to set up Prometheus, [Link](https://devopscube.com/setup-prometheus-monitoring-on-kubernetes/)

Comment: How do you expose pod level metrics at the mentioned end point? Do we need to add something special in the application's kubernetes deployment file?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You have to add this three annotation to your pods:

```
prometheus.io/scrape: 'true'
prometheus.io/path: '/data/metrics'
prometheus.io/port: '80'
```

How it will work?

Look at the `kubernetes-pods` job of `config-map.yaml` you are using to configure prometheus,

```
- job_name: 'kubernetes-pods'

        kubernetes_sd_configs:
        - role: pod

        relabel_configs:
        - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_scrape]
          action: keep
          regex: true
        - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_path]
          action: replace
          target_label: __metrics_path__
          regex: (.+)
        - source_labels: [__address__, __meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_port]
          action: replace
          regex: ([^:]+)(?::\d+)?;(\d+)
          replacement: $1:$2
          target_label: __address__
        - action: labelmap
          regex: __meta_kubernetes_pod_label_(.+)
        - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_namespace]
          action: replace
          target_label: kubernetes_namespace
        - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_name]
          action: replace
          target_label: kubernetes_pod_name
```

Check this three relabel configuration

```
- source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_scrape]
    action: keep
    regex: true
- source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_path]
    action: replace
    target_label: __metrics_path__
    regex: (.+)
- source_labels: [__address__, __meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_port]
    action: replace
    regex: ([^:]+)(?::\d+)?;(\d+)
    replacement: $1:$2
    target_label: __address__
```

Here, `__metrics_path__` and `port` and whether to scrap metrics from this pod are being read from pod annotations.

For, more details on how to configure Prometheus see [here](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration).

Comment: Note: this does NOT work when using prometheus-operator! E.g. when installing the kube-stack-prometheus chart, because it uses PodMonitors instead. See https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/kube-prometheus-stack#prometheusioscrape

Answer (score 16):

The [link](https://devopscube.com/setup-prometheus-monitoring-on-kubernetes/) provided in the question refers to [this ConfigMap](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bibinwilson/kubernetes-prometheus/master/config-map.yaml) for the prometheus configuration. It that ConfigMap is used then prometheus is already configured to [scrape pods](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#pod).

For that configuration (see `relabel_configs`) to have prometheus scrape the custom metrics exposed by pods at `:80/data/metrics`, add these annotations to the pods deployment configurations:

```
metadata:
  annotations:
    prometheus.io/scrape: 'true'
    prometheus.io/path: '/data/metrics'
    prometheus.io/port: '80'
```

See the [configuration options](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#kubernetes_sd_config) for Kubernetes discovery in the prometheus docs (scroll down) for settings related to scraping over `https` and more.

Edit:
I saw Emruz Hossain's answer only after I posted mine. His answer currently lacks the `prometheus.io/scrape: 'true'` annotation and specified `=` instead of `:` as annotations' name/value separator which is invalid in yaml or json.