# How to scrape metrics from postgresql helm deployment with kube-prometheus-stack

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, prometheus-operator, kube-prometheus-stack

I have seamlessly been using `kube-prometheus-stack` for monitoring.

after realizing there is `metrics:` section in `values.yaml` file, I wanted to enable metrics for both existing deployments;

1. postgresql (https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/postgresql)
2. cassandra (https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/cassandra)

### for cassandra deployment

altering the value of key `enabled:` from `false` to `true` was sufficient. After upgrading helm release with new values, a sidecar container is created. I confirmed that I do see the metrics displayed at `/metrics`. I see targets are listed and being scraped in Prometheus.

```
metrics:
  enabled: true
```

### but for postgresql deployment

doing the same did not work; setting

```
metrics:
  enabled: true
```

resulted in creation of a sidecar container, metrics are displayable at `/metrics`. But it is not listed nor being scraped in Prometheus.

**so my question is:** why is this same setting giving the desired result for cassandra deployment but not for postgresql? am I missing something and what else do I need to check?
Also, I don't need to enable `serviceMonitor` for these deployments(?) because prometheus can scrape pods based on annotations, right?
Any help is appreciated.

### annotation config

`additionalScrapeConfigs` in `values.yaml` file of `kube-prometheus-stack` is edited to work with `prometheus.io/*` annotations. (ref: [Monitor custom kubernetes pod metrics using Prometheus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53368018/14320738))

```
prometheus:
  prometheusSpec:
    additionalScrapeConfigs:
      - job_name: 'kubernetes-pods'
        kubernetes_sd_configs:
          - role: pod
        relabel_configs:
        - source_labels: [ __meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_scrape ]
          action: keep
          regex: true
        - source_labels: [ __meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_path ]
          action: replace
          target_label: __metrics_path__
          regex: (.+)
        - source_labels: [ __address__, __meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_port ]
          action: replace
          regex: ([^:]+)(?::\d+)?;(\d+)
          replacement: $1:$2
          target_label: __address__
        - action: labelmap
          regex: __meta_kubernetes_pod_label_(.+)
        - source_labels: [ __meta_kubernetes_namespace ]
          action: replace
          target_label: kubernetes_namespace
        - source_labels: [ __meta_kubernetes_pod_name ]
          action: replace
          target_label: kubernetes_pod_name
```

### versions

```
kubectl version: 
  v1.22.6
chart versions:
  kube-prometheus-stack-35.0.3
  postgresql-11.1.28
  cassandra-9.1.9
```

Comment: using the additionalScrapeConfig is merely to help you find a solution if prom-operator native ways don't work. I'd always advocate against going down that route. In your case, you can set `metrics.serviceMonitor.enabled` to enable the serviceMonitor and then make sure that your `serviceMonitorSelector` in the prometheus instance matches with the labes of the newly created serviceMonitor