# ActiveMQ "Classic" and ActiveMQ Artemis integration with Prometheus

Tags: kubernetes, activemq-classic, prometheus, activemq-artemis

In my existing projects I'm using `prometheus.io/path`, `prometheus.io/port` and `prometheus.io/scrape` annotations in `deployment.yml` to scrape metrics from the pods.

Now I'm trying to integrate Prometheus with ActiveMQ "Classic" and ActiveMQ Artemis, and I want to understand why do I need to use [this plugin](https://github.com/jbertram/artemis-prometheus-metrics-plugin) to fetch these metrics.

Wouldn't using the same annotations in Artemis' `deployment.yml` do the work?

Comment: Any feedback here?

Comment: Based on your answer and (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53365191/monitor-custom-kubernetes-pod-metrics-using-prometheus), I figured out we already have configuration in place to scrape metrics from pod to Prometheus. We just needed a plugin implementation for ActiveMQ message broker. We ended up using jmx-exporter plugin for ActiveMQ Classic and your plugin for Artemis. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless there's some logic behind those annotations which configures the broker to expose metrics then you'll need to do that configuration yourself. For ActiveMQ Artemis the [plugin you linked](https://github.com/jbertram/artemis-prometheus-metrics-plugin) is the recommended approach.