# Prometheus: scrape scalable Kubernetes pod metrics

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

I'm have a Kubernetes deployment of a pod with a `/metrics` endpoint for Prometheus to scrape. The pods are scalable so they can scale out or in.
How can i add IP of these pods dynamically to my Prometheus' config so it can scrape them all?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Monitor custom kubernetes pod metrics using Prometheus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53365191/monitor-custom-kubernetes-pod-metrics-using-prometheus)

Comment: Prometheus collects metrics via a pull model over HTTP and the below mentioned link might be useful to you. https://medium.com/kubernetes-tutorials/monitoring-your-kubernetes-deployments-with-prometheus-5665eda54045